# Spring MVC- Filtering x-forwarded-for headers

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using an spring mvc application, where my server is giving me x-forwarded-for header but somehow spring is filtering those headers.
Spring version is 4.1.6.RELEASE.

Any suggestions? In google I can only find solution for spring boot application.

Comment: i'm getting x-forwarded-port &  x-forwarded-proto only  x-forwarded-for is missing..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Spring consumes the x-forwarded-for header. The original ip address can be recovered using `request.getRemoteAddr()`

If you still need the original x-forwarded-for header, you can use a ForwardedHeaderFilter. [Spring docs link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server)